# Optimize execution time of a ldap research

Tags: php, ldap

I generate a directory of people for my society with pictures etc. like a social media. There are like 1000+ users in the LDAP and it takes so long to perform the research which permits to get all users on screen.

It's exactly this part which takes between 4 and 7 seconds to perform a research:

```
do {
            ldap_control_paged_result($ldap, $pageSize, true, $cookie);
            $sr=ldap_search($ldap, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);
            foreach ($info as $in) {
                if(isset($in[$GLOBALS['nom']][0])){
                $array[0][$inc]=$in[$GLOBALS['nom']][0];
                $array[1][$inc]=$in[$GLOBALS['prenom']][0];
                $inc++;
            }
            }
            $test++;

            ldap_control_paged_result_response($ldap, $sr, $cookie);
    } while($cookie !== null && $cookie != '');
```

I don't know how to optimized it, 5 seconds to generate a page which has a limit of 24 users per page is not possible..

It's not a server side problem because when I execute this research with exactly same filters, same dn USING Apache Directory Studio it takes less than 1 second...

Comment: In your code, you loop through pages to get all users. Why don't you just get one page and display it, and then load the next users if there's a need to change page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LudovicPoitou said in his comment, you loop through all your users in the directory.

For each 24 user in ONE page you display in your web app, your request the entire directory.

I guess from your question that`$pageSize` is equal to 24, so what you do is retrieve every users of your directory with page of 24 users per requests.

Then for 1000 entries you make 42+ requests to retrieve 1000+ users to display only 24 of them on each page of your app.

You should requests all these users by page of said 1000 users only one time and make the pagination client side with the complete set of users.

This is a misunderstanding of the use of page result, it is not a pagination result where you want result 0 to 24 and next request is result 25 to 49, etc.
(At least not in your web app configuration with php because you are not in a stateful connection with the directory where you do the next search with the cookie on user input)

EDIT :

To illustrate what I mean by `not stateful`. When the PHP script end its execution, every variable are destroyed, and so the connection made to the LDAP server. Then the cookie attached to the paged control is not usable anymore as it is linked to the search request made. Than the diagram is like :

```
STATEFUL


    CLIENT             BACKEND               LDAP
      +                   +                   +
      |    REQUEST page1  |                   |
      | +---------------> |  CONNECT + BIND   |
      |                   | +--------+------> |
      |                   |  SEARCH PAGE 1    |
      |                   | +---------------> |
      |                   |      RESPONSE     |
      |      RESPONSE     | <---------------+ |
      | <---------------+ |                   |
      |                   |                   |
      |   REQUEST page 2  |                   |
      | +---------------> |    SEARCH PAGE 2  |
      |                   | +---------------> |
      |                   |     RESPONSE      |
      |     RESPONSE      | <---------------+ |
      | <---------------+ |                   |
      |                   |  DISCONNECT       |
      |                   | +---------------> |
      |                   |                   |
      |                   |                   |
      +                   +                   +


STATELESS


    CLIENT               PHP                 LDAP
      +                   +                   +
      |    REQUEST page1  |                   |
      | +---------------> |  CONNECT + BIND   |
      |                   | +--------+------> |
      |                   |  SEARCH ALL PAGES |
      |                   | +---------------> |
      |                   |      RESPONSE     |
      |                   | <---------------+ |
      |                   |  DISCONNECT       |
      |      RESPONSE     | +---------------> |
      | <---------------+ |                   |
      +                   +                   +
```

Comment: Yes but to do that I need an offset... I don't know how to use this with an offset... I understand the problem but how to avoid to search all and not only 24 users everytime I need to create pages... Do you want the entire function with my pagination system ?

Comment: @Srithovic It's not a question of offset. You can't do pagination search with a stateless connection like php and a webapp implied. This could only work if each loop of your `do {} while` was controlled by the user input and not by the fact there is still entries to fetch. What you should do is return every users entry as a dataset to the client and let the client render this dataset with a pagination if you need it, but do not redo this request on each page change on the client

Comment: @Srithovic As a picture is worth a thousand words, I made a schema to explain what happened when you make the request in your PHP code. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: So my function returns my array sorted, and I add the page number as paramater when the clientcall the function and in my for() (which permitt to display users), I write
for($i = $pageSize*($currentPageNumber-1); $i < $pageSize*$currentPageNumber;i++) 
that could works ? I don't have access to our LDAP today I'm in a Client society.

Comment: @Srithovic No. PHP does NOT work like that. Paged control result is an extended operation on the LDAP protocol which the cookie is linked to the request made to split the response on multiple response, not to make paginated searches. When the PHP script ends, the cookie is destroyed as well as every other variables in your php script, the LDAP connection is closed, the request disappears, etc.

Comment: I meant if I do that I remove the ldap_page_result part, just asking for all users, storing them in array, sorting array, returning array. Client is asking for $i index to $j index of this array depending on page ? I'm a bit lost about how to realize what you're talking about

Comment: @Srithovic to make it straight : the only benefit of using the paged result control for this case is to avoid a sizelimit on the server which could prevent you from returning more than 1000 entries for example. If you do not have size limit on your server, yes you can remove everything related to page control, it is useless.

Comment: Alright thanks, i'll try on Monday, hope there is no sizelimit on the server

Comment: @Srithovic If there is a sizelimit, keep you code as it is, set `$pageSize` to a number inferior to the size limit, and return your `$array`, it will do exacly the same. The only difference is that instead of returning every entry in one go, the server will return them by sample of `$pageSize` entries

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, I'll tell you if it worked !

Comment: It's way faster, but now it takes like 2 second to load every page. How to improve the speed ? We already have a java app which is way faster to load results from pages, is it php which is taking more time ?

Comment: @Srithovic If the answer resolves your issue, I suggest you close it and ask a new one with the element you have now, what is your current problem, and where in your code your are stuck, else this post will loose its purpose. In the new question include you php code, your client code (javascript?), etc, everything which could help improve your problem, with the corresponding tags